# Can't resolve export default from 'xxxx' in index.js vscode when ctrl/cmd click imports

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

When i'm cmd clicking on a import it can't go to the definition of the component if i use a unnamed default export. It works when I do a named export.

**src/components/Component/Component.js**

```
// When i cmd/ctrl click here it should go to OtherComponent.js but it doesn't work
import OtherComponent from 'components/OtherComponent';

const Component = () => null;
```

**src/components/OtherComponent/index.js**

```
export default from './OtherComponent';

/*
if I change it to this it works

import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';

export default OtherComponent;
*/
```

**src/components/OtherComponent/OtherComponent.js**

```
const OtherComponent = () => null;

export default OtherComponent
```

**My jsconfig**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the reason I typically advise against using `export default` - see more information here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: I'm a part of a team, and all the other uses webstorm and it works like a charm for them. I'm trying to get it to work with vs code, and i guess changing how we do this is not an easy solution :)

Comment: I too use IntelliJ and we have issues with the above; would definitely be interested in how they fixed it

Comment: Darek: first mark src as resource or what its called. Right click on the folder. Then Settings -> Code style -> javascript -> import  option is called something with relative paths.

Comment: Yeah, relative/absolute paths work fine...I meant the issue with intellisense and using export default

Comment: Any update to make it work with `export default` ?